# How to pass query params to procedure?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

```
PROCEDURE drawComponent (title IN VARCHAR2) IS
BEGIN
    htp.p('<tr>');
    htp.p('<td class="row-hdr"><strong>' || title || '</strong></td>');
    for rec in (SELECT CELLS.ID as CELLID, CELLS.NUM as CELLNUM, CELLS.A_ID as ID, TBL.REMOVED as REMOVED FROM CELLS LEFT OUTER JOIN TBL ON CELLS.A_ID = TBL.ID ORDER BY CELLS.NUM)  
...
```

I need to add `CELLS`, `A_ID`, `TBL` as params to above procedure. I am not sure on types and syntax.

Clarification:

Procedure will be called multiple times, for different tables, different columns. The body is same, only those params I mentioned are different.

Comment: What do you mean by "to add `cells`, `a_id`, `tbl`" as params? Please use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/27314371/edit) link under your question to further elaborate on this matter.

Comment: To re-use the same code for multiple calls. I've updated my question.

Comment: If you need to decide upon the Table Names and Join conditions at execution time you will need to use the Dynamic SQL
you can `DBMS_SQL` or `EXECUTE_IMMEDIATE`  along with types for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can (ab)use `DYNAMIC SQL` to pass the table name as `parameter` to the `procedure`.

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE
  2  PROCEDURE p(
  3      table_name IN VARCHAR2)
  4  AS
  5  TYPE ref_typ
  6  IS
  7    REF
  8    CURSOR;
  9      var_ref ref_typ;
 10      emp_no NUMBER ;
 11    BEGIN
 12      OPEN var_ref FOR 'SELECT EMPNO FROM '||table_name;
 13      LOOP
 14        FETCH var_ref INTO emp_no ;
 15      EXIT
 16    WHEN var_ref%NOTFOUND;
 17      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('empno --> '||emp_no);
 18    END LOOP;
 19    CLOSE var_ref;
 20  END;
 21  /

Procedure created.
```

Let's execute the procedure and see.

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> BEGIN
  2     p('emp');
  3  END;
  4  /
empno --> 7369
empno --> 7499
empno --> 7521
empno --> 7566
empno --> 7654
empno --> 7698
empno --> 7782
empno --> 7788
empno --> 7839
empno --> 7844
empno --> 7876
empno --> 7900
empno --> 7902
empno --> 7934

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: How can I modify above, to query `'SELECT * FROM '||table_name`, then access each column using dot, e.g. `rec.EMPNO`? What type of variable rec should be, to fetch `INTO`?

Comment: or at least how to query and fetch multiple columns using above method?

Comment: You need to use `COLLECTION` type. Search for `%ROWTYPE`.

Comment: ok, just created `row CELLS%ROWTYPE` and now can access columns. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. If the answer helped you then please mark it answered. It would help others looking for similar issue.

Comment: There is another problem though, for which I will open new question.